# Could not find record error while deleting record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to delete a record by passing id of that record. The code looks like this:

```
def destroy_catalogue_entry
    @catalogue_entry = CatalogueEntry.find(params[:catalogue_entry_id])
    if @catalogue_entry.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Catalogue entry deleted successfully.'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Failed...'
    end
  end
```

I'm getting an interesting error. When my function `destroy_catalogue_entry` is called it shows:

```
Couldn't find CatalogueEntry with 'id'=16
```

but as I comment If condition section and render `@catalogue_entry` as json, the output is printed successfully. So how is it possible? Am I making some silly mistake or is there logical reason. Please enlighten me.

Comment: what is the sql query being generated in the console at the time of this action ?

Comment: can you do these actions in the console and give the output here

Answer (score 2):

Solved! All I did is this:

```
 def destroy_catalogue_entry
    @catalogue_entry = CatalogueEntry.find(params[:catalogue_entry_id])
    if @catalogue_entry.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Catalogue entry deleted Successfully'
      redirect_to action: :view_catalogue_entries, dc_id: @catalogue_entry.dc_id
    else
      flash[:success] = 'Failed...'
    end
  end
```

When I notice the console, the record was getting deleted successfully but after that there was a `SELECT` query for the same record, that is why it was throwing the error **Couldn't find CatalogueEntry with 'id'=16**. As I redirected it, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think destroy method is returning an object. In ruby anything other than false or null will be taken to true in if statement. You can do puts on destroy method and see what its returning.

Answer (score 0):

i presume your,

```
@catalogue_entry = CatalogueEntry.find(params[:catalogue_entry_id])
```

is returning that error because it cant find CatalogueEntry with id 6, make sure you have CatalogueEntry with that id.

Comment: You are right, the issue was same but in different way. Now its solved. I have added the answer for same.